# С помощью localStorage сохраняйте и восстанавливайте список дел между перезагрузками страницы

Tags: javascript, html, localstorage

Выводит [object Object] в списке между перезагрузкой страницы,подскажите,как корректнее можно задействовать localStorage, либо как мне можно подправить мой код для правильной работы моего приложения.

```js
(function(){
    // создаём и возвращаем заголовок приложения
    function createAppTitle(title){
        let appTitle = document.createElement('h2')
        appTitle.innerHTML = title
        return appTitle 
    }

    // создаём и возвращаем форму для создания дела
    function createTodoItemForm(){
        let form = document.createElement('form')
        let input = document.createElement('input')
        let buttonWrapper = document.createElement('div')
        let button = document.createElement('button')

        form.classList.add('input-group', 'mb-3')
        input.classList.add('form-control')
        input.placeholder = 'Введите название нового дела'
        buttonWrapper.classList.add('input-group-append')
        button.classList.add('btn', 'btn-primary')
        button.textContent = 'Добавить дело'
        button.disabled = true

        buttonWrapper.append(button)
        form.append(input)
        form.append(buttonWrapper)
        
        input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(input.value.length>0){
                button.disabled = false
            }if(input.value.length==0) button.disabled = true
             });

        return{
            form,
            input,
            button,
        }
    }

    // создаём и возвращаем список элементов
    function createTodoList(){
        let list = document.createElement('ul')
        list.classList.add('list-group')
        return list;
    }

    function createTodoItem(name){
        let item = document.createElement('li');
        // кнопки помещаем в элемент, который красиво покажет их в одной группе
        let buttonGroup = document.createElement('div')
        let doneButton = document.createElement('button')
        let deleteButton = document.createElement('button')
        
        //устанавливаем стили, а также для размещения кнопок
        // в его правой части с помощью flex
        item.classList.add('list-group-item', 'd-flex', 'justify-content-between', 'align-items-center')
        item.textContent = name


        buttonGroup.classList.add('btn-group', 'btn-group-sm')
        doneButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-success')
        doneButton.textContent = 'Готово'
        deleteButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger')
        deleteButton.textContent = 'Удалить'

        // вкладываем кнопки в отдельный элемент, чтобы они объединились в один блок
        buttonGroup.append(doneButton)
        buttonGroup.append(deleteButton)
        item.append(buttonGroup)

        //приложению нужен доступ к самому элементу и кнопкам, чтобы они объединились в один блок
        return{
            item,
            doneButton,
            deleteButton,
        }
    }

    function createTodoApp(container, title, todoItemsDefault, key){
        let todoAppTitle = createAppTitle(title)
        let todoItemForm = createTodoItemForm()
        let todoList = createTodoList()

        if (localStorage.getItem(key) !== null) {
        let todoItem = createTodoItem(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)))
        todoList.append(todoItem)
        todoItem.doneButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            todoItem.item.classList.toggle('list-group-item-success')
        })
        todoItem.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            if(confirm('Вы уверены?')){
                todoItem.item.remove()
            }
        })
      }

         if(todoItemsDefault){
            todoItemsDefault.map(item=>{
                let todoItem = createTodoItem(item.name)
                todoList.append(todoItem.item)
                todoItem.doneButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
                   todoItem.item.classList.toggle('list-group-item-success')
               })
               todoItem.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
                   if(confirm('Вы уверены?')){
                       todoItem.item.remove()
                   }
               })
                if(item.done){
                    todoItem.item.classList.add('list-group-item-success')
                }
            })
         }

        container.append(todoAppTitle)
        container.append(todoItemForm.form)
        container.append(todoList)

        todoItemForm.form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
            // чтобы страница не перезагружалась
            e.preventDefault();
            if(!todoItemForm.input.value){
                 return 
            }
            
            let todoItem = createTodoItem(todoItemForm.input.value)
            localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(todoItemForm.input.value))
            
           // добавляем обработчики на кнопки 
            todoItem.doneButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
                todoItem.item.classList.toggle('list-group-item-success')
                
            })
            todoItem.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
                if(confirm('Вы уверены?')){
                    todoItem.item.remove()
                    localStorage.removeItem(key)
                }
            })
            // создаем и добавляем новое дело с названием из поля для ввода
            todoList.append(todoItem.item)
            
            // выставляем кнопке disabled
            todoItemForm.button.disabled = true
            // обнуляем значение в поле, чтобы не пришлось стирать его из поля для ввода
            todoItemForm.input.value = ''
            
        }) 
    }
    window.createTodoApp = createTodoApp
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <title>TODO</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script defer src="todo-app.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            createTodoApp(document.getElementById('todo-app'), 'Мои дела',[
        {name: 'Сходить в магазин', done: true},
        {name: 'Купить хлеб', done: true},
     ],'myKey')
        })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container mb-5">
          <nav class="nav">
              <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Мои дела</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="dad.html">Дела для папы</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="mom.html">Дела для мамы</a>
          </nav>
      </div>
    <div id="todo-app" class="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 let todoItem = createTodoItem(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)));
```

Эта функция возвращает вам объект с полями `item, doneButton, deleteButton`.

А на следующей строке вы добавляете списку этот объект, а не элемент:

```
 todoList.append(todoItem);
```

Нужно так:

```
todoList.append(todoItem.item)
```